# How to "convert" while loop in a recursive function

Tags: scala, recursion, while-loop

I am starting with Scala and am having a hard time thinking functionally.

I have the following variables:

```
val dateTimeBegin = Calendar.getInstance()
dateTimeBegin.set(2016, Calendar.MAY, 25, 12, 0, 0)
val dateTimeEnd = Calendar.getInstance()
dateTimeEnd.set(2016, Calendar.MAY, 25, 16, 0, 0)
var slotsString = List[String]()
var slots = List[Calendar]()
```

Then, I wrote this while loop:

```
while (dateTimeBegin.getTime().compareTo(dateTimeEnd.getTime()) == -1) {
  slotsString = dateTimeBegin.getTime().toString() :: slotsString
  dateTimeBegin.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 50)
}
```

It basically picks the dateTimeBegin and dateTimeEnd and creates slots of 50 minutes.

This is the output that the while loop gives:

Wed May 25 12:00:00 WEST 2016
Wed May 25 12:50:00 WEST 2016
Wed May 25 13:40:00 WEST 2016
Wed May 25 14:30:00 WEST 2016
Wed May 25 15:20:00 WEST 2016

However, I know that this is not the correct way to program in Scala and I should use a recursive function.
I tried to write this function:

```
def fillSlots(l: List[String], cB: Calendar, cE: Calendar): List[String] = {
    var s = List[String]()

    if (cB.getTime().compareTo(cE.getTime()) == -1) {
      s = cB.getTime().toString() :: s
      cB.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 50)
      fillSlots(s, cB, cE)
    } else {
      return s
    }
  }
```

But the function doesn't return anything.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of things worth commenting.

First of all, your idea of recursive function is not wrong, given that you simply wanted to re-write the "while version". You just need to make this small fix:

```
// var s = List[String]()
var s = l
```

By the way, not sure if 50 minutes is a typo and should be 60, just checking.

A piece of advice: in the "else" section you should remove the `return` keyword because it it wise to avoid it in Scala. Last calculated value is what's returned from a function so you don't need it at the end of a function (like in your case now), and returning from the middle of a function is strongly discouraged.

Now, onto bigger issues. You said "this is not the correct way to program in Scala". I would agree, but the fact that you're using a `while` loop is not an issue; `while` is a completely legit way to loop over stuff. Of course, `map` is preferred, but `while` is not "forbidden" (e.g. sometimes you may have extremely long lists and recursive function would blow a stack so `while` is a perfectly valid choice).

The real issue is the fact that you're using `var`s (mutable variables). Here's how you can re-write your function without them:

```
def fillSlots(cB: Calendar, cE: Calendar): List[String] = {
  if (cB.getTime().compareTo(cE.getTime()) == -1) {
    cB.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 50)
    cB.getTime().toString() :: fillSlots(cB, cE)
  } else Nil
}
```

Due to the nature of recursion, this list will go from the earlier points in time onwards (e.g. 13:00, 13:50, 14:40 etc).

Don't get discouraged; the fact that you're striving to write Scala code "the proper way" is the most important thing. You will learn all the stuff you need as you go. Most important piece of advice I can give you at this moment is to try to write every piece of code without using mutable variables (vars).

Comment: Further improvement: You even don't need 'l' if I am correct. Simply return Nil in else case and omit the first  parameter. The list is constructed automatically.

Comment: You are right. I modified undisp's example, didn't really look for further improvements. Thanks.

Comment: There were multiple good answers, but this one was the most clarifying. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

There's an almost completely mechanical way to convert any while loop into a tail recursive function.  Let's consider the case where you are using the while loop *only* to set some state.  (You're not printing or whatever, which causes side effects that disappear somewhere.)

Fundamentally, while loops without distant side effects look like this:

```
while (test(state)) {
  state = f(state);
}
```

And that becomes

```
def loop(state: State): State =
  if (test(state)) loop(f(state))
  else state
```

Let's think through what this does.  We go into loop and test the state.  If it passes, we change `state` to `f(state)` and go again.  If it does not pass, we return with whatever state we've got.

And if you look at the while loop--that's exactly what it does too, assuming you recover the state after you leave the loop.

Now, it can be awkward to have all your state in a single object, but there's no reason you can't have multiple parameters.  So, what is your state?  It's `slotStrings` and `dateTimeBegin`.  `slotStrings` starts out empty, which you can mimic with an initial parameter.  And we don't care about all of the state, just `slotStrings`, so we'll only (finally) return that, even though we pass along all of the state in parameters.  So, after cutting out all the unnecessary empty `()`'s (Scala can infer those), we follow the mechanical process and get:

```
def loop(dTB: Calendar, sS: List[String] = Nil): List[String] =
  if (dTB.getTime.compareTo(dateTimeEnd.getTime) == -1) {
    val sS2 = dTB.getTime.toString :: sS
    dtB.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 50)
    loop(dtB, sS2)
  }
  else sS
```

Now, it's customary to not modify things in place (but that's all `Calendar` does--you could use `java.time.LocalDateTime` instead which returns a new instance with its `plus` method), and you could add more parameters to the function (like `dateTimeEnd`) which don't actually change state but can be carried along.

But that's the basic transformation: instead of letting the loop run through again with all the state *implicitly* passed along from iteration to iteration, explicitly name it in a recursive call.

(Note: it won't be tail-recursive if you don't assemble *all* of the state before recursing!  No `loop(foo) + 1`!  You have to pass *everything* forward.  You can still write a recursive function, of course, but it will overflow the stack if it needs to recurse very much.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic recursive approach.

```
import java.util.Calendar
def fillSlots(cB: Calendar, cE: Calendar)(
              acc: List[String] = List(cB.getTime().toString())): List[String] =
  if ((cB.getTime() compareTo cE.getTime()) >= 0)
    acc.reverse
  else {
    cB.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 50)
    fillSlots(cB, cE)(cB.getTime().toString() :: acc)
  }
```

Usage:

```
scala> fillSlots(dateTimeBegin, dateTimeEnd)()
res148: List[String] = List(Wed May 25 12:00:00 PDT 2016, Wed May 25 12:50:00 PDT 2016, Wed May 25 13:40:00 PDT 2016, Wed May 25 14:30:00 PDT 2016, Wed May 25 15:20:00 PDT 2016, Wed May 25 16:10:00 PDT 2016)
```

If you need just a set number of increments you could do something like this.

```
scala> (1 to 6).map{_ => dateTimeBegin.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 50)
     | dateTimeBegin.getTime().toString() }
res151: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(Wed May 25 12:50:00 PDT 2016, Wed May 25 13:40:00 PDT 2016, Wed May 25 14:30:00 PDT 2016, Wed May 25 15:20:00 PDT 2016, Wed May 25 16:10:00 PDT 2016, Wed May 25 17:00:00 PDT 2016)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try to build a call stack on paper. That helps to get a feeling for recursion.

What you want is to use a List[String] as an accumulator, where each iteration adds another element, and in the end get this whole list, when cB >= cE.
When cB < cE you call the function's next recursion.

You even give the list as current state down to the next step, as parameter 'l'.
But instead using it you create a new list instance in 's'. With every step anew.
In the end the condition is false and you return s, but s is the newly created empty list.